# Need open source framework for simple workflow

Tags: java, workflow, chain

A simple workflow is needed in my application.

And I found:

- *Apache chain*: simple and easy use, but it’s just boolean decision (true or false) in a step.
- *jBPM*        : powerful, but heavy. It needs database and specific definition language, steep learning curve as well.

Any open source for such simple workflow in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss Jbpm is best option for workflow based management systems. It is very easy to deploy and integrate into your existing system. And also it provides many other utility task nodes. You can show your workflow execution status at execution time as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could try [Drools Flow](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-flow.html). It is a mature and widely used community project, and it is simpler than jBPM.